# Dropdown with data from db with yii1.1

Tags: php, yii, frameworks, dropdown, yii1.x

I want to create a dropdown list with data from a relational table.
I have a tbl_stock, and on that table I have a relation to other table typeStock, and these connection mades the "type of stock" on the tbl_stock.

So I want to create a dropdownList in the form.

I already tried something like this:

in the controller:

```
 protected function getStockOptions(){
            $stockArray = CHtml::listData(Stock::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'tipo');
            return $stockArray;

        }
```

in the _form.php view:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'tipo', Stock::model()->findAll()); ?>
```

I can't find a way for this to work, now It's getting a error "stock could not be converted to string".

Comment: Why you're using `Stock::model()->findAll()` in view instead of `getStockOptions()` result?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```php
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'tipo', CHtml::listData(Stock::model()->findAll(),'id','tipo'));
```